# Is there a way to Programmatic connect PM2 to C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, node.js, windows, service, pm2

[connect to PM2 via node.js](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/pm2-programmatic/)

The link above show how to connect to PM2 with node js.
Is there a way to connecet via windows service written in C# or somehow transferring information from PM2 to the windows service?

My service need to preform some oparations according to the status of the running node apps

Comment: On option might be to use [edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/47) which lets you run node directly in C#.

Comment: Great very useful! Thanks